# Displaying data from .txt file in separate rows in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, notepad

I'm completely new to VB.net and have been given a homework assignment. I need to be able to read certain lines and display them in a DataGridView. I have been able to link my .txt file to the DGV however it reads the whole file as opposed to the specific line. I have 4 buttons: btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4.

I added a new button to the form that loads the data from the text file, parses it to a datatable and sets the DataGridView1.DataSource to that DataTable. The second method then creates a new datatable and imports the specified row from the main datatable and shows it in the DGV.

I need to be able to press btn1 and have the data displayed in the DGV and if btn2 is pressed afterwards the data would be displayed in the row under it etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private txtDataTable As DataTable
Private Sub loadFileBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles        
loadFileBtn.Click
txtDataTable = New DataTable("txtContents")

Dim txtContents As String()
Try
    txtContents = IO.File.ReadAllLines("database.txt")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Return
End Try

Dim txtLines As New List(Of String())
txtContents.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) txtLines.Add(x.Split(CChar(vbTab))))

If txtLines.Count > 0 Then
    txtLines.Item(0).ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(x.ToString)))
    txtLines.RemoveAt(0)
End If

If txtLines.Count > 0 Then
    txtLines.ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Rows.Add(x.ToArray))
End If
DataGridView1.DataSource = txtDataTable
End Sub


Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click,         
btn2.Click, btn3.Click, btn4.Click
If txtDataTable Is Nothing Then Return

Dim rowIndex As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(DirectCast(sender, Button).Name.Replace("btn", String.Empty), rowIndex) Then
    rowIndex -= 1
Else
    Return
End If

Dim TempTable As DataTable = txtDataTable.Clone
If rowIndex < txtDataTable.Rows.Count Then
    TempTable.ImportRow(txtDataTable.Rows(rowIndex))
End If

DataGridView1.DataSource = TempTable
```

End Sub

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your code that this is a TAB delimited text file. What if you read the file like this:

```
    Using fileReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(PathToFileAsString)
        fileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        fileReader.SetDelimiters(vbTab)
        While Not fileReader.EndOfData
            Dim currentRow as String() = fileReader.ReadFields
            For Each currentField As String In currentRow
                'Have your way with it.
            Next
        End While
    End Using
```